# Atom IDE opening chrome developer tools

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

Whenever i open atom IDE, chrome developer tools window loads in it. How can i start Atom normally for coding

Check the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have set Atom as the current default URI handler, so seek in the settings for URI handlers[image]

and select the third option, never become the default atom//:URI handler.
This will work and if not try reinstalling Atom.